# How to mute all users of a specific voice channel at once using JDA

Tags: discord-jda

I am currently using JDA to create a plugin to mute all users.
However, I cannot mute everyone at once.
I want to mute everyone at once, but it mutes them all one by one and takes tens of seconds. Is there any good way to do this?
I have given the bot administrator privileges.

## Code

VoicechannelTOKEN is obtained by voiceChannelId.

```
    private void muteAll() {
        VoiceChannel channel = jda.getVoiceChannelById(voiceChannelId);
        if (channel != null) {
            List<Member> membersInVoiceChannel = channel.getMembers();
            for (Member member : membersInVoiceChannel) {
                member.mute(true).queue(); 
            }
        }
    }

    private void unmuteAll() {
        VoiceChannel channel = jda.getVoiceChannelById(voiceChannelId);
        if (channel != null) {
            List<Member> membersInVoiceChannel = channel.getMembers();
            for (Member member : membersInVoiceChannel) {
                member.mute(false).queue(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible.